# Объясните почему не работают методы массива

Tags: javascript, массивы

```js
[].push(1,2).unshift(3).join()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Методы **массива** работают.

[Метод `push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) возвращает количество элементов в массиве, это число, а у числа нет [метода `unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)

[Метод `unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) - также возвращает количество элементов в массиве, поэтому к его результату тоже нельзя применить [метод `join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Comment: Спасибо, о, Добрый человек!